# Raspberry Pi Menu missing on Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

How do I get the Raspberry Pi Menu item back after upgrading to `Raspberry Pi OS`?

After the upgrade I had a "blank" Menu button which merged into the Panel.

Comment: same problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a rather confusing answer at https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=275473&p=1669223#p1669223

I wrote the following to restore the menu

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
cp /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/16x16/places/start-here.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps/start-here.png
cp /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/22x22/places/start-here.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/22x22/apps/start-here.png
cp /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/24x24/places/start-here.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/24x24/apps/start-here.png
cp /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/32x32/places/start-here.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/start-here.png
cp /usr/share/icons/HighContrast/48x48/places/start-here.png /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/start-here.png
cd /usr/share/icons/hicolor
sudo gtk-update-icon-cache
```

Then right-click on the blank icon, select "Menu Settings" and enter "start-here" into the icon box.

NOTE this may be a user induced problem. During upgrade you would have seen the following prompt:-

> The desktop has been updated.
>   To apply the updates, please reboot your Pi, and then select one of the options on the Defaults page in Appearance Settings.

I you don't touch the Appearance Settings/Defaults you may not have a problem, although the upgrade changes a number of customised Appearance Settings, requiring corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting!

I have had a similar problem:

Working on Raspberry Pi OS (32bit) on small Bluetooth keyboard.
Clearly I have hit some wrong keys, as a blank panel appears!

Reading the link in your post gave me the solution to this problem!

Here are my instructions:
[*] Right-click on the blank panel, for a menu.
[*] On the menu that appears, select Add / Remove Panel Items.
[*] On the Panel Preferences window that appears  select the Panel Applets tab.
[*] On that same Panel Preferences window select Add (on the right-side).
[*] From the menu that appears choose Menu.
[*] The word Menu should now appear in the list of added plugins.
[*] Select Menu (so it is highlighted).
[*] On that same Panel Preferences window select Preferences (on the right-side).
(A menu appears - which is also shown in your linked instructions).
[*] Delete the text in the Icon field (box on right of Icon word).
[*] Type in that same box (field) the letters rpi.
[*] Type the number 4 in the Padding field (box).
[*] Click [OK].

Hope it works for you!